# Linking to third party framework with xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, xcodebuild

I have a third party framework (which I have developed) as a sub-project of a command line application in Xcode.

If I build my command-line app in Xcode, it builds the framework, then builds the application, links to the framework.

When I run the built application it correctly looks for framework in the application's current working directory. So:

> otool -L my_application

Gives:

> @executable_path/MyFramework.framework/Versions/A/MyFramework

However, if I build my application from the command line with `xcodebuild`, the built application looks in `/Library/Frameworks/` for the framework and I get the following runtime error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/Versions/A/MyFramework
>    Referenced from: /path/to/my_application
>    Reason: image not found

So, basically `xcodebuild` seems to be not running the necessary command (`install_name_tool -change`?) to update the executable's link to `@executable_path/..`

My `xcodebuild` command is of the form:

```
xcodebuild -project path/to/project.xcodeproj -scheme my_scheme -configuration Release CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=`pwd`/project
```

This is with Xcode 4.6 on OS X 10.8.4